# Why does my function fail when called for longer periods?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I have written this little bit of javascript to collect data from an API, then iterate over days in the response parsing them into rows (to be exported to CSV but I've omitted that as it's working fine).

My issue is that the code works fine for up to around 10 or 12 days, but beyond that it raises:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
```

at the line `for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {`

I assume this is to do with the `jquery.get()` call not completing by the time I need the result to be parsed, but I don't know how I should be doing this properly. Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
Start:<br>
<input type="text" id="startdate" value="2016-04-12" /><br>
End:<br>
<input type="text" id="enddate" value="2016-04-12" /><br>
<br>
<input type="submit" id="downloadBtn" value="Fetch data"/>
<script>
    var startDate;
    var endDate;  
    var fileName;
    var headers = ["date","time","obs1", "obs2"]
    var rows = [headers];

    $("#downloadBtn").click(function() {
        startDate = document.getElementById("startdate").value.split("-").join("");
        endDate = document.getElementById("enddate").value.split("-").join("");  
        url = "https://api.example" + startDate + endDate + ".json";
        fetchData( url );
    });

    function fetchData( url ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.get( url, parseRecords );
    }

    // Extract all data from a query response
    function parseRecords(data, status) {
        var days = data.historic.days;
        for (var i = 0; i < days.length; i++) {
            dayRows = formatDay( days[i] );
            for (var j= 0; j < dayRows.length; j++) {
                rows.push(dayRows[j]);
            }
        }
    }

    // Extract row data
    function formatDay ( day ) {
        var dayRows = [];
        var date = day.iso8601.slice(0, 10);
        var items = day.items;
        // error is raised on the following line, but only for larger responses
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) { 
            var row = [];
            var item = items[i];
            row.push([date]);
            row.push([item.obs1]);
            row.push([item.obs2]);
            dayRows.push(row);
        }    
        return dayRows;
    }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: is the server response the expected output when it fails ?

Comment: it looks like it in developer tools network response

Comment: could you however provide the server json response, please.

Comment: Heads up, you use `dayRows` in `parseRecords` without declaring it using a `var` statement-- this could get skitchy down the road-- you're also using the same var name in `formatDay` but you've declared it with a `var` so it should be fine, but better safe than sorry.

Comment: Just a side query: shouldn't the `event.preventDefault` be in the `$("#downloadBtn").click` callback? Since the `event` would be defined there..

Comment: @n00dl3 There are around 6600 lines of the response it when it goes wrong, but it's perfectly valid json on jsonlint.com. This is currently cut down to anonymise the site.

Comment: Another problem I see is that `parseRecords` is passed as a parameter into `fetchData`, but also used as a function name. It works, but is definitely confusing.

Comment: I really don't think this has to do with asynchronous handling. Your code is already parsing data when it fails, it only fails because there is a day that does not have `items`. Have you tried logging a day when you run into an error? Can it be that some days simply do not have `items`?

Comment: @JamieBull I totally trust you, but getting the object/string/whatever related to the error might help. Let me rephrase : Did you try to unit-test the function with the `day` param that causes the error ?

Comment: Ah, I'm completely wrong here! The issue is the format changes after 10 days. Completely new to asynchronous code so I assumed that would be where the problem lay

Comment: hehehehe... ^_^

Comment: Lesson: never assume! And thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is continuing to run fine, but every 10-12 days the server response fails.  However, your code only expects and handles a successful response from the server-- so if it returns an error of some sort, your code happily plugs along as it got normal data, but then chokes when it doesn't have the input it expects.  I would recommend chaining a `.fail` handler on your `$.get`.

Comment: It receives the whole response in one go, and is totally as expected if I call it using curl. I'm sure the problem is timing-related.